# React-Native Build on iphone 7+

Tags: iphone, react-native

I am new to react native and just started learning it. I have downloaded some sample apps from github and was using them in my learning process. 
I am a true beginner..

I have setup my mac pro with react native and in this case I have downloaded an app called movieapp. I have installed it and when I run it in the simulator it works perfect.

Note: I have a paid developer account with apple for Xcode and I am running version 8.3.1 (8E1000a)

I have changed the app for my signing info.

When I run build this app from Xcode to my iPhone 7+ I get this screen

[iPhone 7+ screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir1mO.png)

Here is a screen shot of the Terminal window that pops up when this is built in Xcode.

[Mac Terminal Screen][2]

Could someone please point me in the correct direction to solve this issue?

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RCCManager.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "ReactNativeConfig.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  // rn-config
  NSDictionary *config = [ReactNativeConfig env];

  #ifdef DEBUG
    jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
  #else
    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
  #endif

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [[RCCManager sharedInstance] initBridgeWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation];

  // RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
  //                                                     moduleName:@"movieapp"
  //                                              initialProperties:nil
  //                                                  launchOptions:launchOptions];
  // rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
  //
  // self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  // UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  // rootViewController.view = rootView;
  // self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  // [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you running Debug or Release scheme of your app on the device. Can you share your AppDelegate.m file or source code of the app ?

Comment: added code above :) Thanks for your review

Comment: The code seems to load the js bundle from the development server for debug scheme. Assuming, you ran the Debug Scheme from Xcode. Is the phone on the same wifi network ? Can you check if you can run the release scheme of the app fine?

Comment: Thanks Agent_hunt

Comment: I run from the terminal in simulator but I am not sure if that is debug or release. I have the iphone 7+ plugged in with lightning cable to the same mac. The phone is on wifi and I only have one wifi network. Hours now still cant get it to work on the iphone